# How to calculate the cosine between two line segments

Tags: vectors

I'm preparing for my college maths exam in 2 weeks time and one question I came across that I'm not fully sure how to answer.

The question is

Calculate the length of the line segments BD, BG, and the cosine
of the angle between these two line segments at the point B.

where B = (3, 3, 3), D = (6, 6, 1), G = (8, 8, 5)

I know I have to use the cosine formula but I am unsure what u and v would be in this case.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

The vectors $$\vec {BD}=3\hat{i}+3\hat{j}-2\hat{k}$$
$$\vec {BG}=5\hat{i}+5\hat{j}+2\hat{k}$$

Length of $\vec{BD}=|\vec{BD}|$

Taking the dot product,
$$\vec{BD}\cdot\vec{BG}=|\vec{BD}||\vec{BG}|\cos\theta$$

which gives the value of $\cos\theta$

Comment: Great! Thank you for this. I ended up getting 34/root22 x root54 and cosine of that will give me 9.446.
Hope that's right, thank you for the help

Comment: @MVantastic What is $9.446$? I read it as the value of cosine. Note that the cosine of any real number lies in the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Oh I see. I cos-1 the value I got from the divison. Before the inverse, I had the value 0.98644, would that be the answer?

Comment: @MVantastic The numerator in your fraction will be 26 not 34.

Comment: You are correct, that's my mistake. I ended up with the angle being 41 degrees,  hopefully that is correct!

Answer (score 2):

You can place $B$ at the Origin. Then corresponding for $D$ and $G$ we would get $D=(3,3,-2)$ and $G=(5,5,2)$. Then you van calculate the magnitudes of the two vectors $OB$ and $OG$ with the distance formula. The cosine can be calculated with the formula $cos\theta=\frac{|dot(OB)(OG)}{|OB||OG|}$

Comment: Thank you  for the help! I think I got it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use the distance formula to calculate the lengths (by the way, the distance formula is just Pythagorean theorem in case you didn't already know) to get the lengths of BD and BG. The distance formula between points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ is reproduced below.
$$Length = \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}$$

Plugging into this formula you get:
$$\overline{BD} = \sqrt{22} $$
$$\overline{BG} = \sqrt{54} =3\sqrt{6}$$

Regarding the cosine, you have two options.  You could use the definition of the dot product or you could use the Law of Cosines.  I'll include both methods and let you choose.  I'd recommend the dot product if you've heard of it and the Law of Cosines if not.

Dot product:

The dot product between two vectors is related to the cosine of the angle between the vectors by the formula below
$$\vec{BD}\cdot\vec{BG}=|BD||BG|cos(\theta)$$

or in words,

> the dot product of two vectors equals the product of their lengths times the cosine of the angle between them.

You obtain the vectors by taking the differences between the x and y coordinates (similar to how you did it in the distance formula
$$\vec{BD}=<(x_B-x_D),(y_B-y_D),(z_B-z_B)>$$
$$\vec{BD}=<-3,-3,2>;\vec{BG}=<-5,-5,-2>$$
$$\vec{BD}\cdot\vec{BG}=26$$

Plug into the dot product formula and solve for $cos(\theta)$
$$26 = \sqrt{22}\cdot3\sqrt{6}\cdot cos(\theta)$$
$$\frac{26}{6\sqrt{33}} = \cdot cos(\theta)$$
$$\frac{13\sqrt{33}}{99} = cos(\theta)$$

Law of Cosines
$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ac\cdot cos(C)$$

You have a and b.  Use the distance formula to find c and solve for $cos(c)$
$$\overline{DG} = \sqrt{24} =2\sqrt{6}$$
$$cos(C) = \frac{24 - 22 - 54}{-2\cdot \sqrt{22\cdot 54}}$$
$$cos(C) = \frac{-26}{-6\sqrt{33}}$$
$$cos(C) = \frac{13\sqrt{33}}{99}$$